# Amazon sp-api incorrect URL encoding / decoding characters while updating quantity

Tags: amazon-web-services, urlencode, amazon-selling-partner-api

I have an issue when including the special characters such as "#" in Amazon Listing API. For example, the sku, HP-2DP98AA#ABC-200621 will be updating the quantity at 20. However, Amazon API responses **InvalidSignature**

I did apply the encoding for the SKU before submitting the request to Amazon, but it is failed all the time. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the AWS documents [selling-partner-api-docs](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/references/listings-items-api/listingsItems_2020-09-01.md#patchlistingsitem) Rest API about how to patch the items URL is **PATCH /listings/2020-09-01/items/{sellerId}/{sku}**. This means that sku need to add in URL which contains "#" like this.

```
/listings/2020-09-01/items/{your sellerId}/HP-2DP98AA#ABC-200621
```

This request URL would be cause the exception or InvalidSignature from AWS , because "#" in URL need to encode "#" to "%23" such as below:

```
/listings/2020-09-01/items/{your sellerId}/HP-2DP98AA%23ABC-200621
```

Also, need to add sellerId, marketplaceIds, and sku parameters as well.

Additionally, AWS4 Canonical Request is like below:

```
AWS4 Canonical Request: '"PATCH
/listings/2020-09-01/items/{your sellerId}/HP-2DP98AA%2523ABC-200621
marketplaceIds={your marketplaceIds}&sellerId={your sellerId}&sku=HP-2DP98AA%23ABC-200621
content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8
host:sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com
x-amz-access-token:Atza|...
x-amz-date:20210831T190152Z
x-amz-security-token:Fwo...

content-type;host;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token
d1809d68......"
```